# Want to call an already running native process from within Adobe AIR

Tags: process, air, adobe, native

What I wanted to achieve is to call an already running native process from within Adobe AIR. Actually from within Adobe AIR, I wanted to trigger something to already running native process so that it (native process) can take further actions based on input.

What I understood from NativeProcess class that it starts a new native process. So what happens if that process is already running on operating system? Will adobe air interact with already running process or will it start a new process independent of the other already running?

Your help is appreciated. Let me know if I was not clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you originally launch the process using the `NativeProcess`class from within Air?

Comment: No, the process is not loaded originally using NativeProcess. It is already running as stand alone process and I want to communicate with it from within Adobe AIR.